# How do I find the source of a console error/warning when running a MEAN Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, mean-stack

So I scaffold a basic app, and run the server with `grunt` and then I get the following message (for example):

> (node:7080) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated.
>   Use require( 'events') instead.

What I'm supossed to do with that? I've 134 files in the project that contain that deprecated code, how do I know which one is giving me the warning? I really enjoy fixing bugs, but it gets quite hard when I can't tell where it is.

Can I force node.js to throw the error stack trace by default instead of the handled message? If so, how?

Comment: can't you simply search for `process.EventEmitter` in your files?

Comment: @JaromandaX Quoting from my own question:
"I've 134 files in the project that contain that deprecated code" (each file may have several occurrences), and yes, I searched for it before asking.

Comment: well, yes, 134 files isn't a lot, and you'll have to fix every occurrence of the deprecated code anyway

Comment: It's a lot when it's code from someone else's framework, where you don't know what they're trying to do (thats the point of reusing code, right? trust them in exchange for saving you some time), plus in the next framwork update that code will be overwritten. If it was my code I'd happily fix all those files. Besides my question was something different.